# Swagger Support for JavaLite project

Tags: javalite

I am new to Javalite and want to use ActiveWeb for building production ready RESTFUL application, so is Swagger support available with Javalite (Activeweb)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for Swagger, however, we really need to add it, as Swagger seems to be getting a hold of the market.

Edit: Open API support has been added, please see the documentation page: https://javalite.io/open_api

Available since v 3.0.